# Azure FHIR: Get RawResource in Plain Text

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, hl7-fhir

I've just started my research on the "Azure FHIR SQL Server Version".

I had some issues trying to get the Json Resource in plain text, since It is stored compressed in the database (as shown in the following lines):

```
select r.RawResource from dbo.Resource r where r.IsHistory=0 and r.IsDeleted=0;
```

```
RAWRESOURCE
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
```

I tried different ways to get it, however no one was successful.

```
select cast(r.RawResource as varchar(max)) VarcharResource, 
CONVERT(varchar(max), r.RawResource, 0) VarcharResource2
from dbo.Resource r where r.IsHistory=0 and r.IsDeleted=0;
```

```
VarcharResource2
‹      „’ËNÂP†çQš®4A""÷àJBtaŒÈÎ¸(-`n)… „w÷›9§Ð4çtfÎÌ?ÿ\J&ÙÈJ¶H1òH>eÍ?”;Î ëL""YJ*_üsþ+´P*œTïW—†´‰Š¤#Mî¹•1x1R{""]¤1ÖHZHôûTjÈÙð¸9úž[±ÜdÍ½Erùfx,9™Ù?”cÉIß”é”£>ófH;üçàõÕaÔâ«s:v·9Šõnh(ÒÎGä i´¾-y]”H}pSëSŒ=0ÖÎª¿JÍÕ§R{qÌþ‹=­tÎ‰™Áâ¤ª3ÓM¼5d‚6'eW9S÷u×äšM>íB›»ë»xS¥†ó˜/dYÇ5o-³íZÉ=ó*b«%ûË™¦øîÿÈœä   äÑ{ÿÌ,ás{]tXó¸;íyì*ñODìü¦2´J,Ëƒç5ÃRµi¡à¨±ëc1Ÿ”œjÓg4­ÚÕ±&ÞíñÜz£[úÛ/ ½ã½µG[Ûâ¬ÄÃ­¯ô(ß   ÿÿ
```

Anybody knows the correct way to get back the Json in plain text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources are Gzipped, so something like:

```cs
string rawResource;
using (rawResourceStream)
using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(rawResourceStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzipStream, ResourceEncoding))
{
   rawResource = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```